# Calling microsoft graph function in typescript/react

Tags: reactjs, graph

I'm new to React and TypeScript. I would like to call the following microsoft graph api in my react app.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

I created this code

```
import MicrosftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
const accessToken:string = "";
 let url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
      let request = new Request(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
            "Scopes": "User.Read.All"
        })
      });
      fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
          response.json().then((res) => {
              let photo:[MicrosftGraph.Photo] = res.value;
              console.log(photo);
          });
        })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
      });
```

I receive the error that **the accessToken is empty**. Is there a way that I can fill the token in my app without setting it dynamically in the code?

Kind regards, 
Anouck

Comment: Well, looking at the second line of your code, I would say that your access token is empty indeed. You may need to fetch it up before making the api call.

Comment: My question is how to do that? I'm new to all of this.

Comment: You would probably have to make a previous call to request for the token.

Answer (score -1):

you can use my method
I first get access token then call query to get data from MS Graph
and can set in css class

```
 var UrlImage;
    var that = this;    
      AuthContext.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", function (error, token) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
        request.open("GET", "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/Photos/48X48/$value");
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.responseType = "blob";

        request.onload = function () {
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {

                UrlImage = request.response;
                //  var imageElm = document.createElement("img");
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    // Add the base64 image to the src attribute
                    // imageElm.src = reader.result;
                    that.setState({ imgURL: reader.result },()=>{console.log('set url in state')})

                    // Display the user's profile picture
                    //document.getElementsByClassName('user-picture-box')[0].appendChild(imageElm);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
            }
        };
       // debugger;
        console.log('request:', request)
        request.send(null);
    });
```